# Is touching my wife's anus with my fingers haram? (without leading it to anal sex)

Tags: sex

I'm only wondering if it is haram to touch my wife's anus with my fingers without leading it to anal sex

Answer (score 0):

**No**, touching one's wife's anus with his fingers is not Haram because it does not violate the rules of sex or husband-wife intimacy.
See this for Halal and Haram things of sex: [Etiquette of Sex in Islam](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/5560/etiquette-of-sex-in-islam)